# How to change the asihttp error messages?

Tags: iphone, ios4

How can I change the ASIHttp error message "A connection failure occured." in iPhone. Is there any delegate method for this?

I want to show some another message if the server is inactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that is hardcoded in the `ASIHTTPRequest.m` file. It is on the 3424th line as `NSString *reason = @"A connection failure occurred";`. I suppose you could make a method for it.

Comment: I had done this. But don't think this is a proper method. There may be some delegate methods to change the message.

Comment: I believe if there was a method, the reason String would be a property and not allocated just for use in the method it is in.